# Configurar o sublime 3 para compilar NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sublime-text

Estou a 2 dias procurando uma solução para fazer o sublime 3 compilar um app de NodeJs que tenho. Já tentei várias [soluções encontradas na internet](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=pt-BR&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124544/how-to-run-node-app-with-sublime-text&xid=17259,15700021,15700186,15700191,15700253,15700256,15700259&usg=ALkJrhhnN4swHs8Krs8kGzFJr8RHZMrjPw).
Eu utilizo Windws 7 de 32bits, e já baixei o NodeJs, assim como o TypeScript.
O erro que dá é:" ÒXITO: o processo "node.exe" com PID 8256 foi finalizado."
Alguém saberia alguma forma de resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Mostrar `ÒXITO: o processo "node.exe" com PID 8256 foi finalizado.` não é um erro. O plugin [Nodejs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Nodejs) executa um comando antes `taskkill /F /IM node.exe` para finalizar um processo node anterior aberto, ai depois ele executa `node c:\caminho\para\arquivo.js`.

Quando `taskkill` não consegue encontrar o processo vai aparecer `ERRO: o processo "node.exe" nÆo foi encontrado.` ou se achar um processo já aberto aparece `ÒXITO: o processo "node.exe" com PID 8256 foi finalizado.` e depois o script e executado normalmente.

Certifique-se o Nodejs esteja configurado no `PATH`.

[image: Executar sem um processo node aberto]

[image: Com um processo node já aberto]